# Android Take Photo and Save to Variable

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I would like to allow the user to take a photo, and when finished, have it passed directly into a variable (Bitmap preferably) instead of saved to memory. I've tried using the default android camera intent but cannot seem to stop it from saving to memory and showing up in the gallery.

Any suggestions?

What I have so far is this:

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 1);
}
```

But this saves the picture in the gallery. I would like to get the image without saving it in the gallery.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I've tried the basic android photo taking technique which is using an intent to start the camera. This will pass in the data of the photo for the result, as a bitmap. However, this still saves the image to gallery. I just don't want the image saved.

Comment: maybe you could add some code of how you are calling the intent and how you would like to get the image in you app. I don't think you will get much help without showing your initiative. After all I can imagine that there are many ways to get your image – one would be to read it again from storage and delete the original file, although this could eat quite some memory if you don't compress the image directly

Answer (score -1):

Here's a nice example given at official android developer site: http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Hope this would be helpful.

Comment: Please provide the important points relative to op's question. Link-only answer are considered low quality posts even if they do answer the question.